# Core Data SUBQUERY with key-path collection causes SQL error

Tags: sql, core-data

I'm experiencing a SQL error from a Core Data-generated query. Here's the data model:

[image: Data Model]

I want to get all of the drivers for whose busses have active passengers. This is simply described by the following fetch request and predicate, which works:

```
NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Driver")
NSPredicate(format: "ANY bus.passengers.active == YES")
```

However, let's say I want to do a more complex query on the passenger, like they are both active and a balance above 100. To do such a query, I'd have to use a `SUBQUERY`, like so:

```
NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(bus.passengers, $passenger, $passenger.active == YES 
AND $passenger.balance > 100).@count > 0")
```

I would expect `SUBQUERY` to accept a keypathed collection as its first argument. It generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 0, 
       t0.z_pk, 
       t0.z_opt, 
       t0.zbus 
FROM   zdriver t0 
WHERE  (SELECT Count(t2.z_3passengers) 
        FROM   zbus t1 
               JOIN z_1passengers t2 
                 ON t1.z_pk = t2.z_1busses 
        WHERE  ( t0.zbus = t1.z_pk 
                 AND (( t2.zactive = ? 
                        AND t2.zbalance > ? )) )) > ?
```

And the error: `'no such column: t2.ZACTIVE'`. It looks like it's missing a `JOIN` on the `ZPASSENGER` table.

Is this a Core Data bug or is there a different way to write this predicate?

**Update:** [Here's a sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r64qfb0mdx3g2if/Keypathed%20Subqueries.zip?dl=0) that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Not sure why this is not working, but you could try fetching the `Bus` entity instead, shortening the key path. Please let us know if that works.

Comment: Looks to me like a *limitation*, not a bug.

Comment: I don't think there's anything better than @Mundi's suggestion of fetching on `Bus`. I'd file a bug report with Apple about this, because even if it's a limitation it's one that should be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, fetching the `Bus` entity works. But I want the results of the fetch to be items of the `Driver` entity.

Answer (score -1):

Try fetching the `Bus` entity, avoiding the key path in the first argument in the `SUBQUERY`.

As was pointed out, this can be viewed as a limitation or a bug.

**Update**:
Further research suggests that your subquery predicate should actually work. I would recommend to check your `NSManagedObject` subclasses and make sure `passengers` returns a collection and `active` is properly listed as an attribute.

Comment: I can indeed fetch the `Bus` entity, but that's not really what I'm looking for. This is a simplified version of my actual code. This fetch request is being used in an `NSFetchedResultsController`, and the actual predicate has other queries on the `Driver` entity.

Comment: I also disagree that it could be counted as a limitation, since it causes a SQL error rather than a Core Data error.

Comment: If it is a one-to-one relationship between `Driver` and `Bus` you **can** fetch the `Bus` entity and use the `driver` attribute for your predicates.

Comment: Please also see my update: I think your predicate might actually be quite OK.

Comment: I double-checked and my data model is set up correctly. I am not using any `NSManagedObject` subclasses, just entities. Feel free to check out the sample project I added to my question.

Comment: OK, that is the error. If you did not do subclasses (why not?) the expression `passengers.active` will not be comprehensible to the compiler.

Comment: That's not correct. The compiler doesn't know anything about the contents predicate itself. That's a runtime responsibility of CoreData. I defined the entities correctly in the data model. For the purposes of the sample project, I kept things simple but it wouldn't make a difference. In my full project, I have indeed subclassed `NSManagedObject` with the exact same results.